Western movie with a priest protagonist vs a sheriff villain
I watched this movie on TV a while ago(in the 90s), so the details are quite vague. 

The events occur in a typical Wild West setting
The protagonist is a priest having some trouble with his superiors, a 'Father Brown' type
He is accompanied by some young rogue who is on the path of redemption
They get in a small town ruled by a ruthless sheriff who has outlawed churches, is in league with criminals and terrorizes the population (the main antagonist)
The priest despises fighting, but is good at it. He has a dagger (stiletto-?) disguised in a cross.

The title, year of production/release or other credentials are unknown. Country is USA most likely, as the actors spoke American English.

Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this movie. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of the movie or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. If you have added any of these details, very good. However, if you recall something, be it as the smallest detail, feel free to edit your question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title. Also see How to Ask Identify-this-X questions. Thank you.

Sounds like The Wrath of God (1972), a sort of irreverent Western where a rogue priest played by Robert Mitchum joins forces with a younger Irish adventurer (and an older English man) to battle some deranged despot ruling over a (Mexican?) town that hates the Catholic church (and priests). Mitchum does conceal a knife in his crucifix; he also carries a pistol in his bible and a machine gun. Co-starring Frank Langella as the villain and Rita Hayworth in her final role.




(...Not to be confused with Werner Herzog's Aguirre, the Wrath of God, also from 1972.)
